# What is the equivalence of the setting resolution 72 in ghostview, when using ghostscript?

Tags: tiff, ghostscript, postscript

When I use ghostsview to convert a postscript file to tiff I use the format 72, but if I want to have the same format when using ghostscript which resolution should I use?
for example

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r????? -sOutputFile=a.tif a.ps
```

It seems like it is

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r600 -sOutputFile=a.tif a.ps
```

But it isn't perfectly correct.

EDIT:
What I mean is that in ghostsview, which is the gui version of ghostscript, I can set the resolution for lets say "tiffcrl" to 72, 96, 204x196 and 204x98. What I want is to get the same output that I get when setting resolution to 72 in ghostview, as when I use Ghostsript gswin32c.exe

What are the default settings in gsview so I can transfer them directly into the command line prompt so the output results will be the same?

EDIT2:
The version of gsview is 4.9 and the installed version of ghostscript is 9.01, my operating system is windows 7 32bit, I only have one ghostscript edition installed.

What I do is opening a Postscript-file with gsview and then i press "Convert" under "File". After that I choose the device tiffcrle and the resolution 72. All other options anywhere are default(I haven't messed with them so to speak).
The file I get when doing it this way has a resolution of 4958x7017.

When I do it with ghostscript

`gswin32c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffcrle -r72 -sOutputFile=a.tif a.ps`

I get a much smaller file (kb wise) with a resolution of 595x842, with a totally crappy resolution.

I've also tried the same command but using -r600 which gives me a file with the same resolution as the gsview made file, but it has a different size (kb wise).

When I try the command you provided me @pipitas:

`gswin32c.exe -o nul -sDEVICE=tiffcrle -c "currentpagedevice {exch ==only ( ) print == } forall" | findstr /i resolution`

I get the result

`/.MarginsHWResolution [204.0 196.0]
  /HWResolution [204.0 196.0]`

When I've tried that resolution under -r204x196 it still won't give the same output.

Best regards!

Comment: @Joe: You want a higher resolution and better quality. This you can get, but it comes with a price: the price is paid with a bigger filesize. Usually, you cannot get both: higher resolution/better quality ***AND*** smaller file size.

Comment: @Joe: to verify your TIFF output details, please run this command on each of your results:  `identify -verbose file.tif`. Look for your real image dimensions and resolutions there. (identify is part of the ImageMagick suite of applications and is available for all major OS platforms.)

Comment: @Joe: You say your GS command gives you a "small" file with a *"resolution of 595x842"*. This is a misunderstanding. Resolution is measured in *Dots per Inch* (dpi), and your command explicitely asked for *72 dpi*. What the 595x842 represents is the output *page dimension* measured in PostScript points. Same for your *4958x7017* result. Since `72 points == 1 Inch` (by definition), at 72dpi a dimension of 595x842 gives you a page size of 8.26in (==210mm) by 11.69in (==297mm). At ~200dpi a dimension of 4958x7017 points translates into a page size of 24.3in (=617.2mm) by 35.8in (=909.3mm).

Comment: @pipitas: After installing Imagemagick and using identify it seems as the resolution is 600x600 for the both the images. 
What differs is under "gray:" mean:, standard deviation:, kurtosis:, skewness:.
The file made with gswin32c have a little higher values on the mean, kurtosis and skewness, but a little bit less on standard deviation, I guess this is what makes the difference? Anyway to control this when making the file with gswin32c?

Comment: @Joe: the info bits and pieces you're providing do not fit together somehow. Without the actual files you're using there is no way for for me to analyse what's going on....

Comment: @Joe: So for both files `identify` says they are 600x600 for resolution?! Even though you used `-r72` for the GS commandline?!?! What does identify tell you about *Filesize:* and *Number Pixels:*?

Comment: No I haven't used -r72, I use resolution 72 in gsview, but for some reasone the resolution becomes 600 apparantly. And with gswin32c I use `-r600` because I saw that they were the most similar in terms of page dimension (both are 4958x7017). But even though they have the same resolution and page dimension the files differs in standard deviation, kurtosis, mean and skewness.

Comment: @Joe: Did you see my second answer?

Comment: @pipitas: Yes I did, and I have tried that previously but it still won't generate the "Exact" same file as when I use gsview :/
I really appreciate the help you're giving me, maybe there isn't a solution to this, and that it just depends on the gsview software that does something differently.

Comment: @Joe: No, GSView is just a GUI frontend. Underneath its surface there is the Ghostscript engine at work, nothing else. I'll install it later tomorrow to re-check myself, and I'll come back to this issue later this weekend....

Comment: @pipitas: It seems like there are some more settings to play around with which affect the outcome A LOT. For example the -dDITHERPPI= option affects alot, although I still haven't gotten the result that I want. Have you looked anything more on the problem?

Comment: @Joe: Can you provide links to:  (a) The original PDF you convert to TIFF with Ghostview;  (b) A TIFF you converted with Ghostview;  (c) A TIFF you produced with the command given in my 2nd answer?

Comment: @pipitas: two tiff files produced from a postscript file.
http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/9581/gsviewtiffcrle72.png
http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/9006/gswin32ctiffcrle600.png
http://www.2shared.com/file/z212AqAg/E1D72CFD-30AD-433A-9823-FD95C2.html

Comment: @Joe: Sorry, this is not *at all* what I asked for. The two image files are PNG, not TIFF. The third file is not the original PDF, but a PostScript file.

Comment: @pipitas: the two files were tif when I created them, and the original file is a postscript file created from a word file.
I uploaded it again to this link:
http://www.2shared.com/file/sZZB9IdV/tifftest.html

Comment: @Joe: if we want to debug the TIFF file differences, we need the TIFF files themselves, not any PNGs made from them....

Comment: @Joe: The TIFF file you named `gsview72.tif` does ***NOT*** have a resolution of 72 dpi. It has 600dpi.

Comment: @pipitas: I know but I chose 72 in gsview. As you can see the sizes of the files are different even though they are made from the same file and have the same resolution. I was wondering if you know of all the different commands that affect the tif output file?

Comment: @Joe: Of course I **do** know of all the different commandline parameters that affect the TIFF output file. But it is too much to ask for a complete tutorial on that topic. You did not tell me which command (with full parameters) **you** used to create your TIFF. Was it exactly the one I gave as an example in my second answer (as I hinted at in item '(c)' a couple of answers up here)....

Comment: @pipitas: gswin32c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffcrle -r600 -sOutputFile=a.tif a.ps
is the commandline I'm using in cmd.
In gsview, I set the tiffcrle and resolution 72.
If I use the same command as you I get a different file which is much smaller than the one I've created with gsview with resolution 72.
It is as the gsview doesn't set it as resolution 72 even though I choose that one and sets it as resolution 600 instead, and with some additional options which makes the output file differ from when I use the command r600 in cmd.

Comment: Hi guys, please don't use the commenting system as a chat room. It is for leaving a few comments and prods for more information to a question or answer, not for long debates. The reason behind this is that most of the time (and this is one of them), a lot if not all the comments belong as edits to the question/answer to make that more complete. If I have to read a half-page answer + 3 pages of comments, the focus on the comments is too big. Please edit in pertinent details into the answer instead. If you really need to chat, find/create a chat-room on the Chat site, link at the top of the page

Answer (score 6):

By default, Ghostscript uses 72dpi resolution for all (pixel) image output devices. But it uses 720dpi for the `pdfwrite` output device. These default values are applied if your commandline doesn't specify a different value, such as `-r200` or `-r204x196`.

To determine the overall dimension of the output page, you can use `-gWWWxHHH` to specify width and height in pixels.

Ghostview is a GUI wrapper around Ghostscript, but made by a different developer/company. Ghostview uses Ghostscript internally as its interpreter and renderer. It allows you to set different `-rNNxMM` resolutions through its GUI.

On Windows, there are two Ghostscript commands:

- *gswin32c.exe*: this outputs everything in the cmd.exe screen and also takes every input from there (if you are in interactive mode).
- *gswin32.exe*: this opens a new window for `stdout` output (and also for input if in interactive mode)

Both these commands accept the `-rNNxMM` and `-gWWWxHHH` parameters. To fully understand how they work, you should play with different variations of

```
 gswin32.exe -rNNNxMMM -gWWWxHHH c:/path/to/file.pdf
```

Anyway, the short answer to your question in the headline is: **The equivalent for setting resolution in Ghostview to 72 dpi, for Ghostscript is: add `-r72` to the Ghostscript commandline parameters. (But this value is used for JPEG, PNG, TIFF and other image output anyway...)**

---

### Update

You can query all the default values Ghostscript is using for a specific output device. Try it for example for `tiffg4` output by running the following command:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -o nul ^
  -sDEVICE=tiffg4 ^
  -c "currentpagedevice {exch ==only ( ) print == } forall"
```

Since your interest is about resolution, modify it like this on Windows:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -o nul ^
  -sDEVICE=tiffg4 ^
  -c "currentpagedevice {exch ==only ( ) print == } forall" | findstr /i resol
```

and you should see this output:

```
  /.MarginsHWResolution [72.0 72.0]
  /HWResolution [72.0 72.0]
```

A different device such as `pdfwrite` will give a different result, because it uses different defaults:

```
C:\> gswin32c -o nul -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "currentpagedevice{exch print ==}forall"|findstr/i resolution

  /.MarginsHWResolution [720.0 720.0]
  /MonoImageResolution 300
  /GrayImageResolution 72
  /HWResolution [720.0 720.0]
  /ColorImageResolution 72
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it seems like this isnt sufficient. The program tells me it uses 204.0 196.0 but when I use that in -r204x196 I still don't get the same result that I was looking for. It is really strange and I have no idea why it's like that, is there anyway to debug gsview so I can see the settings that are applied when I convert with the software?

Comment: @Joe: Just like KenS, I also do not fully understand what you want to achieve. Can you update your question, please? Describe each step you use when converting your file with Ghostview. Then we can tell you which command to use with Ghostscript to achieve the exact same result. Also please tell: *Which version of Ghostscript do you use?* - *Do you have different versions of Ghostscript installed?* - *Which Operating System are you on?* - *Which version of Ghostview do you use?*

Comment: Ive edited my text and written down how I create the files with gsview and which versions. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Ghostscript switches are documented in /gs/doc you could start with Use.html.

Resolution is set with the -r switch, if you want a resolution of 72 dpi you would set -r72
Its not obvious to me what you mean by 'use the format 72', that isn't (or doesn't seem to me) a format. But your command l;ine makes it seem like you want the resolution.

Comment: What I mean is that in ghostsview, which is the gui version of ghostscript, I can set the resolution for lets say "tiffcrl" to 72, 96, 204x196 and 204x98.
What I want is to get the same output that I get when setting resolution to 72 in ghostview, as when I use Ghostsript gswin32c.exe.

Comment: Ghostview is not the GUI version of Ghostscript, its a separate application from Ghostgum Pty which uses Ghostscript. On Windows the 'GUI version' of Ghostscript is gswin32, while the command line version is gswin32c. If you want resolution of 72 dpi then set -r72 on the GS command line.

Comment: Ok I understand, but setting the resolution to -r72 doesnt help though for some reason...are there any other parameter switches that need to be set? the resolution I want is 4958x7017

Comment: @Joe: AFAIU you, with 4958x7017 you mean the *page dimensions* in points. You can specify this by adding `-g4958x7017`.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing how you proceeded with Ghostview in order to create your TIFF output from an input PS file, I am now fully convinced that the following Ghostscript command will achieve the exact same result:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
    -o output.tif ^
    -sDEVICE=tiffcrle ^
    -r72x72 ^
    -g595x842 ^
     input.ps
```

(This assumes that you did leave the default setting in Ghostsview at *"Fixed Page Size"*.